# Dockerize production Linux server

Tags: docker

I got a task to care about a production server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, NGINX, Node.js, MYSQL). Beside backup (which is regular) I want to prepare as much as possible for quick migration (to nonexistent staging and development server and into new cloud server).

I was thinking about "dockerziation" of the running server. Is this possible? 
At least to some point?

Answer (score 0):

dockerziation != virtualization, to put things in docker, make Dockerfile(s) for your app, generally one app per docker file (nginx,node,mysql seperate containers) with minimal os needs (ubi not Ubuntu).

nginx Dockerfile example

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

then build it, and then run it.

```
docker build . -t myapp-nginx
docker run myapp-nginx
```

to hook it into other apps, setup a docker-compose file to create relations between apps and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. Today I found next approach: https://juliensalinas.com/en/dockerize-whole-linux-server/  - this is similar to what I thought.

Comment: I actually wrote this blog post for this exact same situation. Glad it helped you :)

Comment: @JulienSalinas I too have the same need, and Julian, your article has helped tremendously. My case is a little different in that I cannot install docker on the server itself. I have to rsync to a remote computer. If you've experimented with that, can you offer some best-practices insight?

Comment: Great to hear that it was useful @user658182!
I don't have specific best practices in mind concerning rsync though..